# Rails dynamically changing parts of view but using the same method in controller

Tags: ruby, comparative-review, ruby-on-rails, mvc

I have this update method which decides whether to update or recreate(same as update but resets the approval_status and create_date) of the building_approval object. I have the **on_progress?** method on building_approval class to check whether it needs to be updated or recreated so no flags are being passed from the view, the problem is I use this **on_progress?** method on view to change some minor UI in the form, so it is being called twice (once in the view for UI and once in the update method in the controller for deciding whether to update or recreate). I have considered passing to_update param from view to the controller so I wouldn't have to run **on_progress?** method twice but it makes my code look ugly

tldr:

```
def update
    return render :edit unless @building_approval.update(param_building_approvals)

    if(@building_approval.on_progress?)
      @building_approval.reapply
      @building_approval.send_reapply_mail(current_member)
      notice = @building_approval.has_contract? ? 'messages.warning.building_approval_has_contract' : 'messages.info.approval_reapplied'
    else
      @building_approval.after_save_by_apply()
      @building_approval.send_apply_mail(current_member)
      notice = 'messages.info.updated'
    end
    redirect_to prospective_customer_building_approval_path(@customer.id, @building_approval.id),
                notice: t(notice, :name => BuildingApproval.model_name.human)
end
```

or

```
def update
    return render :edit unless @building_approval.update(param_building_approvals)

    if(params[:to_update] == "false")
      @building_approval.reapply
      @building_approval.send_reapply_mail(current_member)
      notice = @building_approval.has_contract? ? 'messages.warning.building_approval_has_contract' : 'messages.info.approval_reapplied'
    else
      @building_approval.after_save_by_apply()
      @building_approval.send_apply_mail(current_member)
      notice = 'messages.info.updated'
    end
    redirect_to prospective_customer_building_approval_path(@customer.id, @building_approval.id),
                notice: t(notice, :name => BuildingApproval.model_name.human)
end
```

which one is better ? the first one's cons is it uses **on_progress?** method twice(in view and in controller) , the cons in the second one is it uses on_progress? once but I need to pass hidden_field to_update params to controller and make ugly if statements

Comment: Any reason not to call that method twice? is it time consuming? you could save the result on a variable if you don't want to call it twice but if it makes sense to call the method twice then I don't see the problem. Adding a hidden field looks like a hack for a problem you don't actually have.